# Single File HTML: Importing function from module within the same doc

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, single-file

I've got a form trying to access two functions that's located all within the same HTML document. The function, dependent on firebase needs to be a module in order to import initializeApp, getFirestore etc.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit(); dataSubmit(); return false;">
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
 <script>
   const formSubmit = () => {
      //works perfectly
   }
 </script>

<script type="module">
   import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js";
   import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-firestore.js";

   const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
   };
   const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   const db = getFirestore(app);

   export const dataSubmit = () => {
      ...
   }
</script>
```

**Error:** "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dataSubmit"

It would be much simpler if. I could import it from another file but for the purposes of meeting client requirements I need to keep everything in this HTML file...

Any advice?

Comment: Module-scoped variables are not visible as `window` properties unless your module explicitly makes them: `window.dataSubmit = dataSubmit;` if you absolutely must use inline event handlers.

Comment: your amazing. It worked. Please write an official answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate but I'm terrible at finding them. I'll add an answer if I can't find a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really follow Quentin's advice in the linked duplicate, but you can expose module "globals" by explicitly creating `window` properties:

```
const dataSubmit = () => {
  ...
};
window.dataSubmit = dataSubmit;
export dataSubmit;
```

This will work, but the whole point of modules and their global behavior is to avoid the long-standing problem of `window` namespace pollution.